# Is pandas.cusum() the same as a statistical CUSUM test?

Tags: python, pandas

I am watching a class on edX about data analytics. My interest was peaked by the ideas behind CUSUM to perform "change detection."
The formula I was told about was:
 S sub t = max {0, S sub (t-1) + (x sub t - mu - C) 
and if:
 S sub t >= threshold T, 
we have detecting an increase (similar for decrease).
Lo and behold, I saw pandas had a cusum function.
However, I do not seem to understand how this works. My data head is:

```
    Year            GDP Growth Rate
1   1930           -0.085
2   1931           -0.064
3   1932           -0.129
4   1933           -0.012
5   1934            0.108
```

My output is:

```
      Year   GDP Growth Rate
1   1930.0         1929.915
2   1931.0         1930.936
3   1932.0         1931.871
4   1933.0         1932.988
5   1934.0         1934.108
```

So it appears it is just adding the columns. I obviously am missing something in my understanding. Is cusum() the method I want? I am trying to see if the "change detection" idea provided detects when a recession, depression or boom starts, just for fun.
I will add before anyone says:
No, it is not homework.

Solution: 
I am looking for Cusum (one example is found here it seems):
https://github.com/demotu/BMC/blob/master/functions/detect_cusum.py
AS user pointed out, cumsum and CUSUM and two different things. My mistake. Thanks.
Also:
See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59895/python-module-for-change-point-analysis

Comment: I don't see any `pandas.cusum`. I see a `pandas.cumsum`, but cumulative sums and CUSUM are different things, even if one uses the other.

Comment: yeah, I believe that is probably my issue.... thanks ;/

Answer (score 2):

Say we have a df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': [1930,1931,1932,1933,1934],
                  'GDP Growth Rate': [-0.085,-0.064,-0.129,-0.012,0.108]})      
df

    Year    GDP Growth Rate
0   1930    -0.085
1   1931    -0.064
2   1932    -0.129
3   1933    -0.012
4   1934     0.108
```

We can take the cumsum of the GDP Growth Rate column to see how it changes, and create a new column called Cumsum:

```
df['Cumsum'] = df['GDP Growth Rate'].cumsum()
df


    Year  GDP Growth Rate   Cumsum
0   1930    -0.085          -0.085
1   1931    -0.064          -0.149
2   1932    -0.129          -0.278
3   1933    -0.012          -0.290
4   1934     0.108          -0.182
```

We can also investigate whether the change is going in the positive or negative direction:

```
df['Change'] = np.where(df['Cumsum'] > df['Cumsum'].shift(), '+', '-')
df

    Year    GDP Growth Rate Cumsum  Change
0   1930       -0.085      -0.085     -
1   1931       -0.064      -0.149     -
2   1932       -0.129      -0.278     -
3   1933       -0.012      -0.290     -
4   1934        0.108      -0.182     +
```

We can also set an arbitrary threshold and see when the cumsum is above or below it:

```
df['Threshold'] = np.where(df['Cumsum'] < -0.2, 'Past Threshold', '-')
df

    Year  GDP Growth Rate   Cumsum  Change    Threshold
0   1930    -0.085          -0.085    -           -
1   1931    -0.064          -0.149    -           -
2   1932    -0.129          -0.278    -     Past Threshold
3   1933    -0.012          -0.290    -     Past Threshold
4   1934     0.108          -0.182    +           -
```

Comment: As user2357112  mentioned abouve, cusum is not the same as cumsum haha. Does your answer still stand on how to perform a CUSUM in python?

Comment: My mind mis-read that completly haha. They are similar but different. CUSUM uses the cumsum value, manipulates it, then compares it to a specific threshold to see if it is larger or smaller. If it is larger or smaller than the threshold it will return that value, otherwise it returns the threshold.

Comment: They are different--Both CUSUM and CUMSUM are iterative processes, but with CUSUM, the thresholding and manipulations are part of the iteration, so you can't (easily?) postprocess a `pandas.cumsum()` result into a cusum result.